# How to call method on multiple objects with similar names and same type?

Tags: python, object, simplify, repeat

How might I go about simplifying this code, preferably putting it into a loop or one line?

```
object1.callMethod()  
object2.callMethod()  
object3.callMethod()  

difObject1.callDifMethod()  
difObject2.callDifMethod()  
difObject3.callDifMethod()
```

I know that I can put the objects in a list and iterate through that, however, that would still require two separate loops and two separate lists. Is there any way that I can make a singular list of [1,2,3] and use that to distinguish between the three different objects of each type, since the numbers are in the object names as well?

Comment: There are ways to do the kind of thing you're asking about but could you show real code for these classes/functions? That will help inform useful answers.

Comment: This is the only style of simplification that I'm looking for -- if this is doable, that is all I need. If I were to put all the code for these classes and functions here, it would be hundreds of lines.

Comment: You may also be interested in [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller)

Comment: Related: [How do I create variable variables?](/q/1373164/4518341), esp [TigerhawkT3's answer](/a/38972761/4518341). TLDR: Use a list in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary approach:

```
methods = {cls1.method1: [cls1_obj1, cls1_obj2, cls1_obj3],
           cls1.method2: [cls1_obj4, cls1_obj5, cls1_obj6],
           cls2.method1: [cls2_obj1, cls2_obj2}

for method, objs in methods.items():
    for obj in objs:
        method(obj)
```

This assumes you are using an instance method though.  For a static/class method you'll need to adjust the object being passed for the method.

I'm not sure there's anything elegant that doesn't involve predefining multiples (or combinations) of `lists` and `dicts` and loop over it, since you would need to be explicit in which object runs which methods, a definition is required either way.

---

Ideally, if you have multiple similar objects of the same class, you might opt to instantiate them in a list from the get go:

```
# Instead of this
object1 = Foo(1)
object2 = Foo(2)
object3 = Foo(3)
...

# do this
foos = [Foo(i) for i in range(3)]

# Or this
bars = {name: Bar(name) for name in list_of_names}
```

Then it becomes trivial to manipulate them in group:

```
for foo in foos:
    foo.foo_method()

for bar in bars.values():
    bar.bar_method()
```

While still easy to reference the object on its own:

```
foo[index].foo_method()
bar[key].bar_method()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getattr(obj, method_name)()
```

If all of the method and object names are generally semantic, you can use `getattr` to reference the method based on a string variable, and then call it with `()`.

```
objects = [object1, object2, object3]
for obj in objects:
    getattr(obj, method_name)()
```

If you want to store the objects/method in parallel, use `zip`.

```
objects = [object1, object2, object3]
methods = ['method1name', 'method2name', 'method3name']
for obj, method in zip(objects, methods):
    getattr(obj, method)()
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `eval` function:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    eval("object%d" % i).callMethod()
    eval("difObject%d" % i).callDifMethod()
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this. It does work, [but it makes the code messy](/a/1834754/4518341). And if someone applied it to a different case, where `i` comes from unsafe user input, [it's a security risk](//nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). I think adding a warning to this answer would help.

Comment: There is no reason to suggest `eval` when safer, more specific alternatives are available.